# JSON to CSV: How to create a table column for all fields in a collection when using Papa.unparse()?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, papaparse

I use Papa Parse 4. When I use Papa.unparse(collection) it seems to create the columns of the resulting table from the first document in my JSON collection. I want all possible fields of my collection be represented in the resulting table.

An example:

```
{ "name": "Ross" },
{ "name": "Bob", "age": 63 }
```

creates a table with only one column: "name":

```
name
Ross
Bob
```

I want:

```
name    age
Ross   
Bob     33
```

How do I make Papa Parse use the "biggest" of my JSON objects to create the columns?

Comment: Try making the first object have all the fields you want.

Comment: I use mongoDB. So I would have to somehow order by number of fields. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Papa parse only takes into account the first JSON for generating the headers. Check [this issue](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/246) for more info. However, you can include the fields from all the JSON objects in your final CSV export by using:

```
Papa.unparse({
    data: [ ... ],  // JSON array
    fields: [ ... ] // Fields to include in CSV eg. ['name', 'age']
});
```